# Why do the Area51 question and answer counts not show in accounts tab

Tags: support

On the accounts tab, I see "- questions" on Area 51.

Why does it not pull these values from the Area 51 discussion site?

Comment: I'd assume because the discussion site is basically the equivalent of a site's meta.

Comment: Perhaps, and it is true that the Q and A there have no impact on your reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those question and answer counts are just for the main Q&A sites. They do not include the back-room meta discussions.

The "discussion" of Area 51 is analogous to a type of meta discussion for Area 51, so it is not counted as part of the Q&A network.

Comment: I guess - it just looks a little awkward to have the -'s there. And you wouldn't be able to judge a person's activity with the accounts overview. But I guess it makes sense.